# Forum constantly reloads in flask when submitting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

Ok, so recently i have made this little forum  in Flask that takes information from a form an puts it in a .csv or excel file. My problem is that every time i hit the submit button the whole entire page reloads, starting up the animations again,etc.

What i want done is that once the page has loaded and i press the submit button, i do not want the page to reload, but still keep displaying the information such as next to the form saying  e.g. "thank you for signing in jack".

Every time it does reload, it still does keep the information there, nothing has changed, its just the fact that the page reloads every time which is what i want to stop and have everything else run smoothly. I have heard you can use Ajax but i am not so sure how to implement it. Can someone please help

Here is my code

signin.py

```
    import time
from collections import deque
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv
import re

app = Flask(__name__)

history = deque(maxlen=5)


def sanitise(string):
    return re.sub('[<>]', '', string)

def valid_login(name, email):
    try:
        name.decode('ascii')        
    except:
        return False

    else:

        if len(name) > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def log_entry(name, email, filename = "static/attendance.csv"):
    name = sanitise(name)
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            pass
    except IOError:
        #file does not exist
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write("SIGNIN TABLE \n")
            f.write(time.strftime('%Y-%b-%d \n'))
    finally:
        with open(filename, "a") as f:
                f.write("{0}, {1} \n".format(name, email))
                history.appendleft("Successfully signed in {0}".format(name))



@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def show_form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if valid_login(request.form['name'],request.form['email']):
            print request.form['name'], request.form['email']
            log_entry(request.form['name'], request.form['email'])
        else:
            history.appendleft("Please try again")

            #return render_template('form.jinja', invalid = True, history = history)
    return render_template('form.html', invalid = False, history = history)

@app.route('/attendance', methods = ['GET'])
def get_attendance():
    rdr = csv.reader(open("static/attendance.csv", "r"))
    csv_data = [row for row in rdr]
    return render_template('table.html', data = csv_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8000)
```

My html document

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <title>QAHS Anime Club Signin</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/static/form_stylesheet.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "form_wrapper" style="display:none" >
            <h1>Anime Club Sign In</h1>
            {% if invalid %}
            <h3>Invalid entry. The Name field must not be blank, and can only use ASCII characters.</h3>
            {% endif %}
            <form action = "" method = "POST" > 
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for = "name">Name:</label>
                        <input id = "name" name = "name" autocomplete = "off" spellcheck = false maxlength = "70"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for = "email">Email:</label>
                        <input id = "email" name = "email" autocomplete = "off" placeholder = "Optional" spellcheck = false maxlength = "254"/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Sign In"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id = "history"  style="display:none">
        <center>
        <ul>
            {% for item in history %}
                <li style="color:black; text-align: center">
                    {{ item }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        </center>
        </div>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(

    function(){
        setInterval(function(){

        $("#form_wrapper" ).fadeTo("slow",1.0);

        },500)

        setInterval(function(){

        $("#history").fadeTo("slow",1.0);

        },1000)


});


    </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you process the POST message, you should not render the same page again. Instead it is standard, that you directly redirect to a different page (where you for example could show a thank you page).

This is how web-forms normally are implemented. When you want to change that, you are on your own. I would recommend, that you have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). With jQuery.post() (or $.post()) you can send a POST message without loading a new page. In this case, I would recommend, that you use a different view (not the form-view). Your JavaScript code has to process the result from your POST message on its own. Another standard is JSON -- this format is normally used for AJAX-results.

Edit:

First of all, you have to get rid of the default behavior of the submit button:

Change

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

to

```
<button type="button" id="submit-button" />
```

And than add this JS coding to handle the submit by yourself:

```
$("submit-button").click(function() {
    $.ajax("/receive-post", {"name": $("#name").val(), "email": $("#email").val(), function(result) {
       console.log("Got "+result);
    });
}
```

This coding should give you a small glimpse, how it could look like. For the basics about JSON and how to write the server view (receive-post), you have to find out yourself. That are at least three questions!

I also did not test the coding, it is just a rough direction ...

Comment: Could you please provide the example in my code because i am not so sure how it really works, i had a try and it did not really change anything, soz for being so pushy.

Comment: I added a rough draft how it could work. For the details, you should find out yourself. This is a rather broad thing to answer here.

Comment: What about the rander part of my python code the "render_template('form.html', invalid = False, history = history)", will that cause problems? because it will render no matter what right?